# Laravel regex validation for empty string

Tags: regex, laravel

I have the following validation,
it should match string with letters,numbers,dashes. And empty input should also be valid.
The normal string validation is ok, but I can not make it match "empty" input.

```
'letter_code' => 'regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9\-]*$/'
```

> letter_code format is invalid

**tests**:
"C14"  // valid
"3.14"  //  "format is invalid", as expected
"-"   // valid
""    // "format is invalid", **NOT expected**

Comment: Show your test cases

Comment: @Marcin The test case is the empty string, I guess.

Comment: Is this in a validator? What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to allow and empty string or make sure it’s not empty?

Comment: I mean the code. Regexp looks fine for  me

Comment: does `'letter_code' => 'regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9\-]*$/|min:0'` work?

Comment: @Tomalak `min:0` does not help

Comment: Okay, that's strange.

Comment: yes indeed, I took over this from a colleague.. to show him how regex should be done ... but seems there is something more in to it  :S

Answer (score 10):

I just found out in [laracasts forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/field-validation-null-or-regex), that there is a `nullable` rule.
You can read about it in the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields).

Without the `nullable` rule empty strings are considered invalid if there is a regex rule as well.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer as compared to the one with more up votes at this time.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't add required as additional validator empty string must pass

Here is phpunit test:

```
/** @test */
public function letterCode()
{
    $trans = new \Illuminate\Translation\Translator(
        new \Illuminate\Translation\ArrayLoader, 'en'
    );

    $regex = 'regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9\-]*$/';

    $v = new Validator($trans, ['x' => 'C14'], ['x' => $regex]);
    $this->assertTrue($v->passes());

    $v = new Validator($trans, ['x' => '3.14'], ['x' => $regex]);
    $this->assertFalse($v->passes());

    $v = new Validator($trans, ['x' => '-'], ['x' => $regex]);
    $this->assertTrue($v->passes());

    $v = new Validator($trans, ['x' => ''], ['x' => $regex]);
    $this->assertTrue($v->passes());
}
```

This is tested with Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem in **Laravel 7.x** using **GraphQL Types**. I needed something similar to this in a field called phone or nothig (empty string). So I did something like this:

```
'phone' => [
        'name' => 'phone',
        'type' => Type::string(),
        'rules' => ['regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9\-]*$/','nullable']
```

Here, phone is the name of the field you want to enter text into, and rules is what we define as regex, or NULL.

Hope this helps someone!